# How do I persist a list of subtypes with JPA 2.0?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, jpa-2.0

I have a manager class with a list of visitable elements that I would like to persist in a database using JPA/Hibernate:

```
@Entity
class Elements {
  void accept(Visitor v) {...}
  @? List<Visitable> elements;  // or List<AbstractElement>
}

@? class AbstractElement implements Visitable {}

@Entity class Element1 extends AbstractElement {}
@Entity class Element2 extends AbstractElement {}

class ElementDAO {
  void saveElements(Elements e, EntityManager em) {
    em.persist(e);
  }
}
```

I have tried multiple approaches.  I have tried to mark AbstractElement as @MappedSuperclass, but then Hibernate cannot figure out the correct Visitable type, and won't let me mark it with @OneToMany(targetEntity=AbstractElement.class).  I have tried changing the List to contain AbstractElement but Hibernate complains that it cannot instantiate an abstract class.  I have also tried using TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy on the AbstractElement class and get the same 'cannot instantiate' error.

Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?  Is this doable at all?

I've searched many similar questions on this site dealing with jpa and inheritance, but none of the suggestions have worked.

Update:
So it looks like the issue was not with the method of inheritance or abstract classes per-se, but with the fact that I was trying to use EntityManager::merge() instead of EntityManager::persist().  I believe that has to do with the fact that merge makes a copy of the entity.

So in light of this new knowledge, do I just have to acknowledge that merge cannot work with a collection of a abstract classes?  Or is there some way to add a copy-constructor that hibernate can call?

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell JPA/Hibernate that the content type of the List is an `Entity` (it therefore cannot be an Interface but needs to be an abstract class), that the List represents a relation between Elements and AbstractElement (using `@OneToMany`) and your super element needs to be marked as the top element of a class hierarchy (`@Inheritance`). The inheritance strategy is independent of this and thus arbitrary (default is SINGLE_TABLE):

```
@Entity
class Elements {
  @OneToMany 
  List<AbstractElement>
}

@Entity
@Inheritance
class abstract AbstractElement implements Visitable {}
```

Comment: So I tried this (as I said above) previously, but figured I should try again.  When I do this I get an InstantiationException:  Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: Element
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1215)

Comment: Please see the new Update note in the original question, as yes, your answer is correct if using persist(), but has issues with merge().

Comment: If you have issues with `merge()` then you should (also) post that code... Also, looking at the `CascadeType` annotation for `@OneToMany` might help here.

Comment: Obviously this is hibernate-dependent, but considering I'm using it now, I went through the code to figure out exactly 'why' it couldn't create an abstract class.  What I found was that this particular exception comes from org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator::instantiate().  It will always throw this exception if the entity it is trying to create is an abstract class *unless* the mapped class is Serializable with a non-null id.  Therefore, I added Serializable and an id to the concrete Element classes, and voila, merge now works.